# What regular expression can I use to find the Nᵗʰ entry in a comma-separated list?

Tags: regex, parsing, split

I need a regular expression that can be used to find the *N*<sup>th</sup> entry in a comma-separated list.

For example, say this list looks like this:

```
abc,def,4322,mail@mailinator.com,3321,alpha-beta,43
```

...and I wanted to find the value of the 7<sup>th</sup> entry (`alpha-beta`).

Comment: Must you use regex? How about a `str.split(",")[N - 1]`

Comment: @Amarghosh He might not be using Python

Comment: You don’t want to do it with a straight regex. You want to split it, or better yet, use a CSV-parsing module, and then pull out the element you need from the resulting list.

Comment: Note that “comma-separated” and “comma-delimited” (and for that matter, “comma-terminated”) are different things. Your data is merely comma-separated, not comma-delimited. Also, it’s verging on useless to neglect to specify the programming language or program/application/tool/utility that you hope to use this with, because regex dialects vary wildly, and subtly.

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm using a software package, not a programming language, so I don't have access to any of the "split" type constructs - the package only gives me access to provide a regexp.  It evaluates the regexp in a Hadoop cluster, so I presume it's evalulated by the Java regexp handler.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

My first thought would not be to use a regular expression, but to use something that splits the string into an array on the comma, but since you asked for a regex.

most regexes allow you to specify a minimum or maximum match, so something like this would probably work.

`/(?:[^\,]*,){5}([^,]*)/`

This is intended to match any number of character that are not a comma followed by a comma six times exactly `(?:[^,]*,){5}` - the `?:` says to not capture - and then to match and capture any number of characters that are not a comma `([^,]+)`. You want to use the first capture group.

Let me know if you need more info.

EDIT: I edited the above to not capture the first part of the string. This regex works in C# and Ruby.

Comment: I believe this also works in Java, though you may need to use the group property and it would be the second element in the group array.

Answer (score 0):

You could use something like:

```
([^,]*,){$m}([^,]*),
```

As a starting point. (Replace $m with the value of (n-1).) The content would be in capture group 2. This doesn't handle things like lists of size n, but that's just a matter of making the appropriate modifications for your situation.

Answer (score -2):

```
@list = split /,/ => $string;
$it = $list[6];
```

or just

```
$it = (split /,/ => $string)[6];
```

Beats writing a pattern with a `{6}` in it every time.